# How to get parent control index by clicking child control from TableLayoutPanel c# windows apllication

Tags: c#, windows

I need some clarification, please anyone help me thanks in advance.

I have a panel with multiple controls such us label, datagridview, text boxes and buttons. I added 'n' number of panels dynamically into the `TableLayoutPanel`. I need to transfer records from one datagridview to another datagridview, which one residing in corresponding `TableLayoutPanel`. My problem is, how can I identify the data send to which data grid. Is there any possible to get column index by clicking a child controls.

Comment: Can you show us the source code, and what you've tried already?

Answer (score 0):

Place dummy image objects in each cell. And try this on Drop event of TableLayoutPanel

```
private void tableLayoutPanel1_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    Point p = tableLayoutPanel1.PointToClient(new Point(e.X, e.Y));
    Control c = tableLayoutPanel1.GetChildAtPoint(p);
    int row = tableLayoutPanel1.GetRow(c);
    int col = tableLayoutPanel1.GetColumn(c);
}
```

If you want to know the index of a say button which is being clicked in Gridview...

1- while creating them dynamically store the row-col info in Tag e.g "1-2" and then use it later

2- You can iterate to find row-col to see where this matches.

If you have ref of the DataGridViewCell

Then it's simple:

DataGridViewCell.RowIndex
DataGridViewCell.ColumnIndex